# Develop Print Driver

Tags: windows, sdk

I need to develop a print driver to print from any application into a TIFF file. Does someone know of resources or a good SDK vendor that would enable me to do that? Environment is Windows, any language.

Comment: Edited my answer, might want to recheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Microsoft Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/WDK/default.mspx) (freely available from the linked Microsoft site) has extensive documentation and examples on writing printer drivers. You can check the online [printer driver page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb870492.aspx) of the DDK docs before downloading it.

Edit: One commercial alternative that would probably be much quicker to deploy is [VeryPDF's DocumentPrinter](http://www.verypdf.com/artprint/). It's rather pricy (currently $1500 for a developer license, $399 for a server license), but from what I've heard their support is rather good so if the price is tenable for you this may be a good option.

There's also [a SDK from DirectConvert](http://www.directconvert.com/us/printer/printer_driver/directcontrol.htm), but I couldn't find any pricing info and don't know anything about them.

Depending on your usage patterns, another option would be something like [TechSmith SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.asp), which has printer capture facilities available. This is not a SDK, though.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for something that would be faster to develop, that's why I asked for a commercial vendor.

Answer (score 1):

Create a raster print driver using the Windows DDK.  The sample they provide will do just fine.  This will generate bitmaps, which can then be converted to TIFF using [LibTiff](http://www.libtiff.org/).  Your OEMSendPage function is where you'll want to convert the bitmap to TIFF and save it.  If you're unfamiliar with the DDK and Windows print drivers, expect to spend quite a bit of time on this.

I have source for a driver I used to sell that does exactly what you want, but I stopped maintaining it after NT 4 so it's seriously out of date and would require some significant work to make it useful on modern Windows platforms.

Comment: There's actually a sample XPS raster driver included in the current WDK that produces tiff data, but it is restricted to Win7 (or vista with the platform updates)